# Output CSV row only if 2 columns in 2 csv files match with Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, compare

Newbie with Python.  I have 2 csv files that both have student last name and student first name (Re-enrolledonline.csv and currentschoolroster.csv - the number of columns and column headings are different but both files contain this information).  I then need to create a CSV with a list of students that are NOT found in Re-enrolledonline.csv but ARE in currentschoolroster.csv.  I can match one column without an issue with the code below but I can't seem to find a good resource on how to only write to the new file if BOTH first name and last name columns are matched.

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd



f1 = pd.read_csv('/users/Desktop/CompareFiles/currentschoolroster.csv')
f2 = pd.read_csv('/users/Desktop/CompareFiles/Re-enrolledonline.csv')

notmatched = f1[~f1.Last_Name.isin(f2.StudentLastName)]

notmatched.to_csv('/users/Desktop/CompareFiles/notmatched.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas uses `&` for *and*, `|` for *or* in indexing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

That should work fine:

```py
notmatched = f1[~f1.Last_Name.isin(f2.StudentLastName) \
                & (~f1.First_Name.isin(f2.StudentFirstName))]
```

PS. Beware, if the CSVs were big, `isin()` would be very slow.

Comment: So I jumped the gun a little.  It's finding duplicate last names and then finding duplicate first names but it doesn't look for those things per row.  So my matched file excludes all students who share a last name and then also removes all students that share a first name but it doesn't match FIRST AND LAST NAME in a given row.